# Does an  AsyncTask stops when I close the application?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to upload files from phone to server for that I am using an AsyncTask. In case of large files if they are still uploding and the user closes the application will the upload stop i.e  AsyncTask will end or continue till its complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) in case of large files.

Answer (score 1):

The activity will continue to run even if the user switches to another application, unless you explicitly call `finish()` or the system kills your activity, in case of low resources.