# Will Android interrupt an AsyncTask after the application quits?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am using an AsyncTask subclass to perform loading and saving into a database. When my application exits, it will cancel the task with mayInterruptIfRunning set to false, so that existing db writes are wrapped up and the database isn't left in a partially invalid state. My question is, can I be sure that Android won't forcibly stop my DB task after this point? My hunch is *no*; as such, I need to find some way to ensure that my database is not left in a state where only part of the data is written.

**EDIT:** On second thought, I would rather not even cancel the task on exit. If an AsyncTask is doing database work when my app is stopped or destroyed, I need its doInBackground method to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said here... [Does an  AsyncTask stops when I close the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879712/does-an-asynctask-stops-when-i-close-the-application)
... No. Android will kill the task if the system kills the app in case of low memory. In other cases, you need to stop the AsyncTask explicitly by calling .finish() (for the Activity running the task), or cancel() (for the AsyncTask itself).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you; apologies for failing to find the existing thread.